# Detecting C leak using Instruments (Leaks)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, malloc, instruments

I wrote a test code to check how to use Instrument (Leaks). I have created a single view application and on a button click I have loaded a new view like this...

```
- (IBAction)btn_clkd:(id)sender {
    new_file *new = [[new_file alloc] init];

    if (new) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:new animated:YES];
        new = nil;
    }
}
```

In new_file ViewDidLoad method, I have create a leak like below...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    char *c_mem = (char*) malloc(10000000);
    strcpy(c_mem, "TESTING");
    //   free(c_mem);
}
```

Even I'm using ARC, memory allocated is a plain C malloc, and I have not freed memory after used, even though I have popped and loaded again and again the new view, instrument(Leaks) is not detecting any leak in this code... What is the reason, Am I checking correctly?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your view controller is deallocated (please verify), *eventually* Leaks will detect that `c_mem` pointer leaks.

Instruments may not find this *immediately* - due to the algorithm it uses to detect leaks.

The algorithm is basically searching for *unreferenced* variables looking like pointers which point into the heap. If it *happens* that there is an arbitrary variable, say *p*, whose value happens to be the value of `c_mem` - then Instruments *thinks* that pointer `c_mem` is still referenced from *p* -- even though *p* may contain only arbitrary data and not referencing `c_mem`.

Note that Instruments leak detecting algorithm is actually more sophisticated, and may change and get improved.

In order to find leaks, I always run special code - like unit tests - in a loop. If the used memory does not grow in time, you are usually good. You can also use the "Snapshot" feature of Leaks, and the "Mark Generation" feature of Allocations to check for the current state of the heap.

Answer (score 0):

When you pop your `ViewController`, if nothing has references to it, it is deallocated automatically by ARC with all it's variables. That is why you do not get leaks.

Look at what happens to your controller, when you pop it, using Leak Instrument. Also you can see there a number of references on it. It is very convenient to detect retain cycles also.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a full reference on how to use Instruments.

Comment: A scope of your variable is a method of a class. That's why I think these variables are destroyed after method finishes.

Comment: You are right variable will be destroyed, however I guess not the dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: When you allocate memory, you create a pointer c_mem. This pointer is destroyed, when method finishes. So the memory is freed. Just a hypothesis.